# Modal verbs in reporting

Tags: modal-verbs, indirect-speech, backshifting

'Advanced Grammar In Use' (AGU) by Martin Hewings, UNIT 37 C, says:

> The verbs **could**, **would**, **should**, **might**, **needn't**, **ought to**, **used to**, and **could have**, **should have**, etc. *don't* change in the report:
>
> 'I **could** meet you at the airport.' --> He said that he **could** meet us at the airport.
>
> 'You **should have** contacted me earlier.' --> She said I **should have** contacted her earlier.

Is it possible, though, to have these pairs instead? (These are not from AGU but are made up by myself.)

> 'I **could meet** you at the airport.' --> He said that he **could have met** us at the airport.
>
> 'You **should contact** me.' --> She said I **should have contacted** her.

If these made-up pairs are possible, contrary to what 'Advanced Grammar In Use' claims, is it possible in general that the verbs **could**, **would**, **should**, **might**, etc. *do* change in the report?

If so, is 'Advanced Grammar In Use' wrong about this?

Comment: I edited to bold the infinitives/participles as well, as I find it easier to compare the sentences that way (but feel free to change it back if you disagree). One thing I noticed when doing that is that you actually changed the example sentence: Hewings has 'You should **have** contacted me earlier.' as the direct statement, not 'You should contact me earlier.' Are there any examples that just have *should* in Hewings?

Comment: @sumelic I agree with your edit. I did it the way I did simply because that's the way Hewings did in the book. // The second quote is intended to be different from the original; specifically, 'could have met' in the first line and 'should contact' in the second, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Oh, oops, I didn't realize that the bolding was in the original source! I get that you're making changes intentionally, but I'm not a big fan of changing 'You should have contacted me earlier' to 'You should contact me earlier' because the second sounds a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: @sumelic Think of a context where 'she' was talking about a specific future contact date that she thought was a bit too late. Then, I think she could easily say, 'You should contact me earlier.'

Comment: I checked unit 37.it did not have problem.the first part which is bolded is in AGU and it is correct...the second part ,you bolded, does not seem to be correct ;where did you find it?

Comment: @Lara Sorry for the confusion. The second part is not in AGU. I was simply asking if the second part would be possible.

Comment: You should include any essential information in your question; users shouldn't need to access your textbook to answer your question. I read an early draft of the existing answer; if you feel it fully answers your question now, you should accept it.

Comment: @1006a I believe that I have included all the essential information in my question. Just because someone is mistaken about my question and then I refer them to the textbook cited in my question doesn't mean I have not included all the essential information in the first place. If you have read the other answer and its comments, you should know that I don't feel it fully answers my question. Even the author of the answer is willing to modify the answer after the comments back and forth. So, I'll have to wait for the update on the answer.

Comment: The bottom line answer to your question as-written is ***your examples are wrong; the text-book is not wrong***. I up-voted the original version of KarlG's answer, because it stated that pretty clearly. If that's not sufficient, you need to explain *in the question*, not a twenty-comment thread, what more you don't understand. Your question talks about "modals"; if you specifically want answers limited to the *past tense* of specific modals, you should mention details like that, as well.

Comment: @1006a The very link to the Cambridge Dictionary chart that you have cited in your now-deleted answer shows at least two cases (just below the chart) of possible exceptions to the "rule" of AGU. Once I have pointed that out in a comment to your answer, you have deleted your answer. And you still argues that AGU's not wrong. You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: You're right, I deleted my answer because I realized I wasn't answering what you wanted to know about...but I made the mistake because *you didn't ask that question*. YOUR examples are wrong, as-written. If you want to know about the examples in Cambridge, either use those, or re-write your question to make it clear that you're wondering about something similar.

Comment: @1006a If you're so sure about that, why didn't you edit your answer to show me why my examples are wrong whereas the Cambridge examples are right? You could have distinguished the Cambridge examples from mine by editing your answer, but you chose not to.  Instead, you just deleted your answer. Now, at the very least, AGU's "rule" is contradicted by the Cambridge examples, if not mine. So your statement that AGU's not wrong is not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74604/discussion-between-1006a-and-jk2).

Answer (score 3):

Your examples don't work, as they change the intended meaning of the original speaker:

> 'I **could meet** you at the airport.'
>   *This means it is possible for the speaker to meet at the airport*
>
> He said that he **could have met** us at the airport.
>   *In contrast, this means that at one time it was possible for the reported speaker to meet at the airport, but it isn't anymore*

Think about having a phone conversation with A, while B is sitting next to you. A says "I *could* meet you." B asks "What did A say?" If you report that "A said he *could* meet us," B will know that meeting up with A is a possibility. But if you report that "A said he *could have* met us," B will be left wondering why A *can't* meet. The same kind of problem occurs with changing *should* statements:

> 'You **should contact** me.'
>   *The speaker wants you to contact her, at some point in the future*
>
> She said I **should have contacted** her.
>   *The speaker is disappointed that you* did not *contact her at an appropriate time in the past*

Perhaps your confusion comes from instances when the facts of the situation have actually changed between the original speech and the report of the speech. Cambridge mentions this possibility

> especially where the report looks back to a hypothetical event in the past:
>
> > He said the noise might have been the postman delivering letters. (original statement: ‘The noise might be the postman delivering letters.’)
> >
> > He said he would have helped us if we’d needed a volunteer. (original statement: ‘I’ll help you if you need a volunteer’ or ‘I’d help you if you needed a volunteer.’)

In both of Cambridge's examples, the original statement was expressing a hypothesis or conditional future, and in the reported statement, made some time later, the hypothesis has been (dis)proven or the condition has turned out not to be met (or, in the case of the unexplained noise, perhaps we just don't care anymore since we now know that whatever it was wasn't dangerous). Neither of your examples fits this pattern, so they can't shift the way you propose.

Comment: +1 for the requested edit. But here's a further question: Cambridge and you seem to be saying that the original statement ‘The noise might be the postman delivering letters.’ describes a hypothetical situation. But isn't it just the speaker guessing about what happened in reality, not in a hypothetical situation?

Comment: I'll fix that--the noise example is not a hypothetical future, it's a hypothesis about the past. The material change is that we either find out whether the hypothesis is correct or we decide we don't care. (And I note that my memory of the hypothesis being that the noise was a cat is mistaken...probably because that is always my hypothesis for unexplained noises at night.)

Comment: Thanks. Then, in my own example of _I could meet you at the airport_, IF, before the reported speech is made, it is determined that the original statement cannot be realized, e.g., "he" didn't make it to the airport, then can't you report it like "He said that he could have met us at the airport."?

Comment: @1006a: And you're comfortable with  the "volunteer" example?

Comment: _He said it might have been the cats_ can mean it was or wasn't the cats beyond the immediate situation, when you'd likely use the present. Unlike the other modals, except _could_ when used in the same sense, backshifting doesn't necessarily result in an _irrealis_.

Answer (score 2):

The authors of [*English Language Today*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech), available on the Cambridge Dictionary website, agree with  Hewings that in reported speech modals such as *could, would, should,* etc. admit no change. They do, however, suggest an exception, "especially where the report looks back to a hypothetical event in the past":

> *"The noise **might be** the cats next door."*
>   He said the noise **might have been** the cats next door.

The may also occur when *could* is used in the same sense as *might*:

> *“That **could be** Mr. Brown's noisy Ford.”*
>   He said it **could have been** Mr. Brown's noisy Ford.

They offer this example:

> *He said he **would have helped** us if we’d needed a volunteer.* (original statement: *‘I’ll help you if you need a volunteer’ or ‘I’d help you if you needed a volunteer.’*)

The sentence in indirect speech attempts to do double duty for one conditional that leaves open whether the man rolled up his sleeves and a second where he most likely headed off to the pub. In the first sentence, help is contingent on the need for a volunteer; in the second, there is no such need. This is an important distinction that should be transmitted correctly in reported speech, and indeed easily done, since the first conditional should be rendered:

> *"I'**ll help** you if you **need** a volunteer."*
>   He said he **would help** us if we **needed** a volunteer [so we handed him a shovel].

*Will* goes to *would* and *need* to *needed* according to the standard rule. In the second sentence, where the man himself has determined his help is not needed, reported speech is cast as a contrafactual conditional in the past:

> He said he **would have helped** us if we **had needed** a volunteer [but we didn't, so off for a quick pint].

And this brings up a problem with your suggested examples: an attempt to change tenses with a modal has resulted without exception in an *irrealis*:

> *"I **could meet** you at the airport [if I get off work in time]"*
>   He said that he **could have met** us at the airport [but he didn't because he had a late meeting].

You also offer the example:

> *"You **should contact** me."*

And your suggested transformation:

> She said I **should have contacted** her.

But that isn't what she said.

> *"You **should contact** me."*
>   She said I **should contact** her [so I did at the time she suggested].
>
> *"You **should have contacted** me."*
>   She said I **should have contacted** her [but I thought she meant *next* Wednesday].

This leaves *might* as the sole modal which can permit a change in indirect speech because its meaning of maybe yes, maybe no is preserved. Attempting to do so with other modals completely changes the sense of the original speech unless it was couched as an unreal condition in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm sort of confused by your statement: "This leaves might as the sole modal which can permit a change in indirect speech." What about the _would_ example (_He said he would have helped us if we had needed a volunteer._) earlier?

Comment: I allowed for a change in tense for contrafactual conditionals. _Might_ can change as I said, while the other modals cannot.

Comment: Re the direct speech 'I could meet you at the airport.' Let me ask you about this context. A: _I could meet you at the airport._ B: _No, please don't bother._ Now, B reports to C this conversation with A as follows: (1) B: _He said he **could meet** me at the airport, but I told him not to bother._ (2) B: _He said he **could have met** me at the airport, but I told him not to bother._ Which would you say, (1) or (2), if you were B?

Comment: I would say 1, since that renders the conditional properly from A's POV. Simply because you refused the offer doesn't alter the nature of the original utterance. 2  suggests a different exchange later like "I could have met you at the airport but you told me not to bother."

Comment: Are you saying that (2) would be impossible English?

Comment: @JK2: Only if you alter the second clause to: "if I had not told him not to bother." Then it makes sense.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while. What I don't understand is why the presence of an if-clause should matter. You have said that you wouldn't say (2), because your refusing the offer "doesn't alter the nature of the original utterance." Then, why should simply changing the second clause of the indirect speech from _but I told him not to bother_ to _if I had not told him not to bother_ make (2) make sense, when it still "doesn't alter the nature of the original utterance"?

Comment: What I'm trying to make clear, and apparently failing, is that you have to report _Hey, JK, I could meet you there_ as _He said he could meet me there_.  That maintains the possibility of his meeting you there whether it happened or not. If, however, you report it as _He said he could have met me there_ then there is no possibility of his having met you there, because something hindered him from doing so. Whether that hindrance is your having said not to bother or his car was being repaired isn't important.

Comment: First off, _he could have met me there_ does not always entail that he didn't met me there. The same goes for _he would have met me there_. What I'm saying is that it's not like _might have met_ is the only way of expressing the speaker's uncertainty about what actually did happen. The flip side of that is that _he might have met me there_ can also implicate that he didn't actually meet me there.

Comment: Secondly, when you add the if-clause (_if I had not told him not to bother_) to the indirect speech (_he could have met me there_), as you have suggested, then you're essentially forcing the _he could have met me there_ part to be construed as "he didn't actually meet me there," which is contrary to what the direct speech is supposed to convey. So, I wonder why you're saying that adding the if-clause would remedy the indirect speech even with _he could have met me there_?

Comment: Please give me a sentence where _He could have met me there_ means that he actually did.

Comment: I didn't say it means he actually did. What I said is, it doesn't always entail he actually didn't. Here's an example. A: _Do you know he met her last night?_ B: _I don't know. But I think he could have met her._

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean any sentence, but one in reported speech.

Comment: _I think he could have met her_ **is** a reported speech. And your reasoning in the last paragraph of your answer says "This leaves _might_ as the sole modal which can permit a change in indirect speech because its meaning of maybe yes, maybe no is preserved." But the reasoning depends only on what you think is the unique meaning of 'might' regardless of it being used in reported speech or not.

Comment: Yes, _could_ can be used in the same sense as _might_, except for those speakers of Southern American English who say, _He might could have met her there._

Comment: So, are you changing your mind about _might_ being "the sole modal which can permit a change in indirect speech"??

Comment: Ha, ha, I guess so, could in the sense of might. It didn't occur to me because I'm one of those speakers who's perfectly comfortable saying _might could_. But _It could be the neighbor's cat_ => _He said it could have been the cat_ works fine. I'll change the answer to reflect that usage.

Comment: Thanks. But 'would have met' I think also can denote a conjecture about a past event and not a counterfactual situation. A: _Do you know he met her last night?_ B: _I don't know. But I think he would have met her._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74572/discussion-between-karlg-and-jk2).